# Writing XML to web page

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have an XML file that I generate with C#. The file is great, however, I want (when the xml file is generated) to have it upload to a URL of my designation.

I am unfamiliar with web coding, and have been searching endlessly. This has to be possible!

Comment: Are using ASP.NET web forms, MVC, etc?

Comment: I have narrowed down that I will be using FTP. The page is a single xml file, and this should be what I am needing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're saying, is that you want to upload a file (doesn't matter if it's xml or any other type of file) to a web server.

Usually, you upload files to web servers using FTP. Most of the shared web hostings support this protocol, and of course, if you have your own server- it's really easy to setup and configure a FTP server.

There are many articles about using FTP from C# application. you can try [this one](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/desktopapplications/article.php/c13163/Simple-FTP-Demo-Application-Using-CNET-20.htm) or just google C# ftp.

Comment: what if it isn't an ftpserver he wants to upload to?

Comment: there are other possible ways to transfer data. he can put his own aspx page on the server and get the data to upload in the POST data... but if he's looking for solution - then ftp will probably be the easiest way. and, as i said, most of the shared web hosting provider supports ftp. and if it's his own server - it's really easy to install.

Comment: I was able to ftp the file directly to the folder located on the server. I was able to do this directly from the command line with basic FTP controls, and I was then able to write a C# console application to automate this process. Thanks for all the suggestions I was able to research in the right direction with all the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to open some line of communication between the place that has your XML file and where you would like it to go.  There's probably a lot of ways to do this, refine your search as there are many ways to do this.  In the end you need to either open a stream between the two or you need to have the receiver listen for some kind of signal and then write down the message.

+1 (since I can't do it yet) to the gentleman that suggested WebClient.  One very good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to send data to a resource. There various upload methods.

Comment: I know the irony of just providing a link for this, but adding the context in a comment is a bit hard.. do check [this thread on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/147063 "Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?")